# Vertex won't move

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

When I unwrap my UV map, I always have two vertices that won't move with the rest of their parts. How can I fix this? Below is a picture of one.

I have already turned off UV sync selection and disabled sticky selection mode.

[image: Common vertex]

Comment: Hi, please help me understand your problem. You have an unwrapped UV-map as seen in the picture. I see 4 selected vertices. So when you move these vertices, the other vertices don't move. Is this correct?

Comment: Or when you select everything by pressing 'A', those specific vertices don't move?

Comment: The thing is; I selected only one vertex. However, it seems to be attached or shared with the other parts where it is also lightened up, making it impossible to change the shape of each part. Hope this is clear :)